# Using unique_ptr with vector and map

Tags: containers, unique-ptr

I have a class called Info.

I tried creating a unique_ptr vector to hold a list of this class.

The map contains the key as a string and unique_ptr as the value.

But when I try retrieving the value from the map and try to put it into a vector to form the list, VS2010 compiler gives an error :
error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &&'

```
vector<unique_ptr<Info>> sInfo;
QMap<QString,vector<unique_ptr<Info>>>::Iterator iterMap;
for(iterMap = map_sInfo.begin(); iterMap != map_sInfo.end(); ++iterMap)
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Info>>sValue = iterMap.value();
    sInfo.push_back((sValue)); //error C2664
}
```

How do I make the 
Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you're trying to push back the whole sValue container (which is a `vector<unique_ptr<Info>>` instead of a `unique_ptr<Info>`. As you just noticed, that isn't going too well.

You have a few options. First, you can loop over the content of `sValue` and `push_back` every element. Second, you can use std::copy to add the elements in one statement:

```
std::copy(sValue.begin(), sValue.end(), std::back_inserter(sInfo);
```

A third option is to use std::vector's `insert` function to add the whole container in one go:

```
sInfo.insert(sInfo.end(), sValue.begin(), sValue.end());
```

Comment: Thank you Timo, I did opt for the first option and it did work. But now I am in trouble with the QMap.error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'